# Is there an R technique to group_by, search, and match a long data structure?

Tags: r, boolean, match, tidyverse, text-mining

This is a problem of finding which `id`s have matching `word`s, from a list of 5 words for each `id`.

We have a long data structure from a text mining project with an `id` and the `word`. Each group_id has 5 words. We would like to measure which `word`s from one id are in another `id`. i.e. which id are similar based on there words.

We have tried to use a for loop on the [row, column] but it seems there is a better way.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(id = factor(c(1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
                             4523, 4523, 4523, 4523, 4523, 
                             0984, 0984, 0984, 0984, 0984)),
       word = c("hello", "today", "the", "monkey", "boy",
                "go", "me", "key", "wind", "hello",
                "monkey", "yes", "no", "wild", "quit"))


output <- matrix(1, length(data$id), length(data$id))

for (j in 1 : length(data$id)) {
  for (i in 1 : length(data$id)) {
    output[i,j] <-  data[i,2] == data[j,2]

  }
}

output

## from the output we see that 4 and 11 match.

data[4,]
data[11,]
```

My end goal is to have a matrix with `id` by `id` and the intersections are the number of matching words (0-5).

This is the desired output:

```
#      1234 4523 0984 
# 1234    5    1    1  
# 4523    1    5    0  
# 0984    1    0    5
```

Any suggestion on completely reorganizing the data structure or solutions with this structure are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` `word` by `id` and then use `outer` with a custom function to calculate number of times a word occur between different `id`s.

```
count_value <- function(x, y) {
    colSums(mapply(`%in%`, x, y))
}

outer(split(data$word, data$id),split(data$word, data$id), count_value)

#     984 1234 4523
#984    5    1    0
#1234   1    5    1
#4523   0    1    5
```

Comment: although, I would like to group_by `id` and see how many words for each `id` match to another `id`

Comment: I have added a sample output showing the number of matching `word` between each `id`

Answer (score 1):

We can easily solve it with `tcrossprod` from `base R`

```
tcrossprod(table(data))
#   id
#id     984 1234 4523
#  984    5    1    0
#  1234   1    5    1
#  4523   0    1    5
```

---

Or the same method with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
count(data, id, word) %>%
     spread(word, n, fill = 0) %>%
     column_to_rownames('id') %>% 
     as.matrix %>% 
     tcrossprod
#      984 1234 4523
#984    5    1    0
#1234   1    5    1
#4523   0    1    5
```